# Retrieve logged user data with Alamofire and Swift

Tags: swift, http, cookies, alamofire

I want to retrieve some data from a website where an authentication is needed. I made a first Alamofire request which creates cookies when the user is logged in. Here is how I do this:

```
Alamofire.request("https://example.cim/Users/Account/DoLogin?username=\(userName)&password=\(userPassword)", method: .get).responseJSON { response in

            //print(response.response)

                headers = response.response?.allHeaderFields as? HTTPHeaders

                let cookies: Array = HTTPCookieStorage.shared.cookies!

                print(cookies)
}
```

And I obtain this when I print the cookies:

```
[<NSHTTPCookie version:0 name:"NID" value:"104=eae1--l4zFs3t8O08nZLsi1WMjyRTW2bgPJ82c6krPvClFkLwqJTxAqG5ao5vYXM7FCK2jcya1A6scpIl_O-JZ9GDT7FUKKbcZh9IspeGFJ4x3u_wQQ4jjjh_wckP-9o" expiresDate:2017-11-30 21:16:27 +0000 created:2017-05-31 21:16:29 +0000 sessionOnly:FALSE domain:".google.fr" partition:"none" path:"/" isSecure:FALSE>, <NSHTTPCookie version:0 name:"ASP.NET_SessionId" value:"qk5lrr1snmyrkx521tn3qsub" expiresDate:(null) created:2017-06-01 09:59:55 +0000 sessionOnly:TRUE domain:"extranet.groupe-efrei.fr" partition:"none" path:"/" isSecure:FALSE>, <NSHTTPCookie version:0 name:"extranet_db" value:"68FA3B54DE455AF7E852C0BEB5B13AC684208447E8B9FF1E35F2..."
```

The login was successful and I get an ASP.NET_SessionId.

My issue is that I don't know how to retrieve data from the user that is logged in. I read the Alamofire documentation but didn't find any way to do this.

Thanks in advance for your help.